# Why is middle on the right subarray MergeSort

Tags: mergesort

So I have come across mergesort and noticed that the middle point is stored on the right subarray. Why does one do this? Is this more beneficial? I have tried to find out but could not come across to any documents stating this.

Example in Python when allocating subarrays for left and rgiht

```
    left = [] * midPoint
    for i in range(midPoint):
        left.append(array[i])

    right = [] * (n - midPoint)
    for i in range(midPoint, n):
        right.append(array[i])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you divide an array with an odd number of values into two subarrays, it doesn't matter which subarray (left or right) has one more value than the other. This is simply an implementation detail. The algorithmic complexity will remain the same - O(n*lg(n)).